# Using sum in map with two iterators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to calculate sum of each number in two lists using map and sum. I got a Integer at the end.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
answer = list(map(sum,a,b))

>>> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

but when I wrote a lambda function with two args everything was fine.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]

answer = list(map(lambda x, y : x + y, a, b))
```

what is the reason? What is the behavior of sum in map function?

Comment: what you want to achieve can be done with `list(map(sum,zip(a,b)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each iteration, it will work like `sum(1,2)`which throws that error:

```
>>> sum(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

`lambda x, y: x + y` is the equivalent of `operator.add`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [2,3,4,5]
>>> list(map(operator.add, a, b))
[3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT* `operator.add` is probably what you're looking for (see answer above)

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

> sum(iterable, /, start=0)

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

sum doesn't do what you wish it would.  You can create your own sum that does what you want like so:

```
def mysum(*args): return sum(args)
print(mysum(1,2,3,4,5)) # 15
```